Bell's inequality in Claude Cohen-Tannoudji's Quantum Mechanics Volume III
Claude Cohen-Tannoudji et al, Quantum Mechanics Volume III, 2020 edition, Chapter XXI.F-3-b.$\alpha$ (F-7) on p.2210 states
$$\big\langle\hat A(a)\hat B(b) \big\rangle={\cal P_{++}+P_{--}-P_{+-}-P_{-+}} \tag{F-7}$$
where $\cal P$'s come from the same chapter Equations (B-8)-(B-10) as shown below.

How is this equation (F-7) derived? The authors do not define operators $\hat A$ and $\hat B$. The signs in front of $\cal P$'s in Equation (F-7) resemble those generated from
$$\big(|+\rangle_{\theta_A}-|-\rangle_{\theta_A}\big)\otimes\big(|+\rangle_{\theta_B}-|-\rangle_{\theta_B}\big).$$
But why?

Type the relevant passage using MathJax. See e.g. this.

Page references as well as what edition you're using would be helpful. If you're asking about F-3-a and F-3-b, the relevant content is from those sections, not from elsewhere in the book. The authors define the operators in the equation you quote in the sentence immediately preceding the equation you quoted and the paragraph before the paragraph giving (F-1) and (F-2) is also relevant. As a hint for where the signs come from: what are the various products of $\pm 1$?

@alanf: I have added the page number and edition year. I have said it was from F-3-b with the equation number. The very first phrase of F-3-b.$\alpha$ is "Relation (B-10)..." which is in Section B not in Section F contrary to what you say. $\hat A, \hat B$ -- not $A, B$ --are used for the first time in Equation (F-7) in Chapter XXI Section F but not explicitly defined. If you refer to the sentence in the parenthesis, it only says they are operators not numbers. I do not understand your hint for the sign. Could you please write an answer?

@alanf: I have answered my own question. Feel free to inspect it. As for the statement of the product of $\pm1$, there are of course $4$ cases. I alluded to this in the last two sentences of my question. The question is how this combinatorics is specifically applied, since there are many interpretations and applications of this combinatorics. Option 1 and 2.1 in my answer demonstrate two distinct applications.


Let
$$R(\theta):=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\frac\theta2 & -\sin\frac\theta2 \\ \sin\frac\theta2 & \cos\frac\theta2
\end{bmatrix},\ \theta\in \mathbf R, \quad D := \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}; \\
S(\theta):=R(\theta)DR(\theta)^T=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & -\cos\theta \end{bmatrix}, \quad \text{(diagonalization of $S(\theta)$)} \\
v := [|+\rangle\;|-\rangle],\; v^\dagger = \begin{bmatrix}\langle+|\\ \langle -| \end{bmatrix}, \\
C:=\begin{bmatrix}0&1 \\-1&0\end{bmatrix}, \\
|\Psi\rangle :=\frac1{\sqrt2}[|+\rangle\; |-\rangle]_AC \otimes\begin{bmatrix}|+\rangle\\ |-\rangle \end{bmatrix}_B; \\
u(\theta) := vR(\theta)=[u_+\;u_-].
$$
In the all the prior expressions, the subscript of a matrix applies to each entry of the matrix. I suppose $$\hat A(\theta_a)= v_A S(\theta_a)v^\dagger_A=u_ADu_A^\dagger=u^A_+u^{A\dagger}_+-u^A_-u^{A\dagger}_-, \\ 
\hat B(\theta_b)= v_B S(\theta_b)v^\dagger_B=u_BDu_B^\dagger=u^B_+u^{B\dagger}_+-u^B_-u^{B\dagger}_-; \;\text{(spectral decomposition or diagonalization of $\hat A$ and $\hat B$)}\\
\hat A(\theta_a)\otimes \hat B(\theta_b) = 
 (u^A_+\otimes u^B_+)(u^{A\dagger}_+\otimes u^{B\dagger}_+) 
-(u^A_-\otimes u^B_+)(u^{A\dagger}_-\otimes u^{B\dagger}_+) 
-(u^A_+\otimes u^B_-)(u^{A\dagger}_+\otimes u^{B\dagger}_-)
+(u^A_-\otimes u^B_-)(u^{A\dagger}_-\otimes u^{B\dagger}_-).
$$
With these,
\begin{align}
\langle \hat A(a)\hat B(b)\rangle &= \langle\Psi|\hat A(\theta_a)\otimes \hat B(\theta_b)|\Psi\rangle \\
&= |\langle\Psi|u^A_+\otimes u^B_+\rangle|^2-|\langle\Psi|u^A_-\otimes u^B_+\rangle|^2-|\langle\Psi|u^A_+\otimes u^B_-\rangle|^2+|\langle\Psi|u^A_-\otimes u^B_-\rangle|^2 \\
&= \mathcal P_{++}-\mathcal P_{-+}-\mathcal P_{+-}+\mathcal P_{--}.
\end{align}
which is the desired result.

However, if our sole aim is to prove the second equality of Equation (F-7), i.e.
$$\langle \hat A(a)\hat B(b)\rangle = -\cos\theta_{ab},$$
it is much more straightforward to compute directly. We show the following two approaches.


2.1  \begin{align}
&2\langle\Psi|\hat A(\theta_a)\otimes \hat B(\theta_b)|\Psi\rangle \\ 
=& (\langle +-|-\langle-+|)\hat A\otimes\hat B (|+-\rangle-|-+\rangle)  \\
=& \langle +|\hat A|+\rangle\langle-|\hat B|-\rangle
-\langle-|\hat A|+\rangle\langle+|\hat B|-\rangle
-\langle +|\hat A|-\rangle\langle-|\hat B|+\rangle
+\langle-|\hat A|-\rangle\langle+|\hat B|+\rangle  \\
=&A_{1,1}B_{2,2}-A_{2,1}B_{1,2}-A_{1,2}B_{2,1}+A_{2,2}B_{1,1} \qquad\qquad (A=S(\theta_a),\;B=S(\theta_b))\\
=&-\cos(\theta_a)\cos(\theta_b)-\sin(\theta_a)\sin(\theta_b)-\sin(\theta_a)\sin(\theta_b) -\cos(\theta_a)\cos(\theta_b)  \\
=&-2\cos(\theta_a-\theta_b)
\end{align}
2.2 In general
\begin{align}
\langle\Psi|\hat A(\theta_a)\otimes \hat B(\theta_b)|\Psi\rangle &= \sum_{i,j,m,n}c_{i,j}^*(v_i^\dagger\otimes v_j^\dagger)\hat A\otimes\hat B\, c_{m,n}(v_m\otimes v_n) \\
&=\sum_{i,j,m,n}c_{i,j}^*\langle v_j,\hat Bv_n\rangle c_{m,n}\langle v_i,\hat Av_m\rangle  \\
&=\sum_{i,j,m,n}c_{i,j}^*B_{j,n}c_{m,n}A_{i,m}  \\
&=\frac12\operatorname{tr}(CBC^\dagger A^\dagger)
\end{align}
where $c_{i,j}$ is an entry of matrix $C$, $A$ and $B$ in the last two lines denotes matrices with respective entries $A_{i,m}=\langle v_i,\hat Av_m\rangle$ and $B_{j,n}=\langle v_j,\hat Bv_n\rangle$.
Here we have
$$A = S(\theta_a),\quad B=S(\theta_b),$$
and
$$CBC^\dagger A^\dagger=-\begin{bmatrix} \cos & -\sin \\ \sin & \cos\end{bmatrix}(\theta_a-\theta_b).$$
So
$$\langle\Psi|\hat A(\theta_a)\otimes \hat B(\theta_b)|\Psi\rangle = -\cos(\theta_a-\theta_b).$$
